# Change limit size for interactive SVG generated

Tags: doxygen

I have an esthetic problem with the generated documentation by Doxygen 1.8.13.

When I check the option **INTERACTIVE_SVG** for unknown reasons, 2 graphs with the same number of nodes appears differently see below :

[Image with not Pan & Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4SyO.png)

[Image with Pan & Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks2nT.png)

How we can change the limit size when Doxygen transform the SVG generated into an interactive SVG ?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the images inline and not as links. Also specify the version of doxygen also a, small, reproducible example would be an advantage.

Comment: Stack not permit me to add image inline only links because reputation score is under 10.

Comment: @lxigrec Please specify the version of doxygen and also add a, small, reproducible example.